# k8S Ingress and IPVS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ipvs

I am new to k8s, and I have a question regarding the use cases of ingress and IPVS.

According to what I have read in several articles on the internet, ingress is used for load balancing in north-south traffic toward pods. There are several ingress-solutions out there, like traefic-nginx-haproxy, etc.
Here comes my question, what is the use case of IPVS transport-layer load balancing?
Can we use it for the east-west traffic between pods..?

Please correct me if I have a misconception of the above.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

IPVS is layer 4 load balancing at linux kernel level.

i read somewhere it can handle around 100,000 forwarding requests per second.

> Even though Kubernetes already support 5000 nodes in release v1.6, the
> kube-proxy with iptables is actually a bottleneck to scale the cluster
> to 5000 nodes. One example is that with NodePort Service in a
> 5000-node cluster, if we have 2000 services and each services have 10
> pods, this will cause at least 20000 iptable records on each worker
> node, and this can make the kernel pretty busy.

Example : https://blog.titanwolf.in/a?ID=00700-de778e7d-72e7-4515-b822-18844b104abd

https://dustinspecker.com/posts/ipvs-how-kubernetes-services-direct-traffic-to-pods/

Question

> what is the use case of IPVS transport-layer load balancing?

You can use the **IPVS** with **external IP** to expose the service running inside the K8s cluster instead of ingress.

> Can we use it for the east-west traffic between pods..?

Yes, you can use it. You can run the **kube-proxy** in to the **IPVS** mode.

So Kube proxy has three modes **userspace, iptables, or IPVS**

If i explain **iptables** VS **IPVS** in very simple words,

there is not much performance changes until you are running around **1000** services and **10000** PODs in the cluster. If you are operating at that level using the IPVS with Kube-proxy might can help you and improve performance.

If you aren’t sure whether IPVS will be a win for you then stick with kube-proxy in iptables mode. It’s had a ton more in-production hardening.

You can checkout this document for more : https://www.tigera.io/blog/comparing-kube-proxy-modes-iptables-or-ipvs/